# genealogytree pgfkeys Error

Tags: tikz-pgf, genealogytree

I am running a simple genealogy tree example, but get an error message concerning pgfkeys package, when I put the option: [template=signpost]. It does not allow centering:

! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/halign', to which you pass

How do I solve it?

I am working with windows 8 system and running MikTex2.9 from TexMaker 4.2. I cannot automatically upgrade, my internet server does not allow me

---

```
\documentclass[landscape]{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
%======================================
\begin{document}
%======================================
\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[template=signpost]{
parent{
c[id=na1,female]{Hija 1 \, \\ \gtrsymBorn\, Sta. Fe, 11 Ago   }
g[id=na2, male]{hijo 2\, \\ \gtrsymBorn\, Sta. Fe, 11 Ago }
p[male]{pap\'a\, \\ \gtrsymBorn\, Zaragoza, 8 Ene  }
p[female]{mam\'a\, \\ \gtrsymBorn\,Asturias, 5 Ago }
}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your code runs on my up-to-date TeXLive 2018 distribution without problems when compiled with `pdflatex`. Which compiler do you use, and which installation?

Comment: Hi. I am working with windows 8 system and running MikTex2.9 from TexMaker 4.2. I cannot upgrade, my internet server does not allow me.